# jquery - how to get properties from object Object?

Tags: jquery

My php class is returning an array of object Objects, and I'd like to call or select attributes of each one.

My JS looks like this:

```
$.get("getData.php", function(result){
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

            $.each(data, function(i, v){
                    console.log($(this).attr('myPlantCode'));
```

...but the console just returns 'undefined' for each object in the array.

I know it must be something simple and I'm probably not far off...but how do I call out specific attributes by name?

Comment: Your didn't even close your $.each statement

Comment: If you use `$.parseJSON` in a jQuery AJAX callback you are doing something wrong. jQuery already does that for you...

Comment: @ThiefMaster I don't think it does that unless you specify the data type or use `$.getJSON()`.

Comment: You're iterating over `data` but you're trying to access `this`, as if it's a DOM node. You need to use `i` and `v` passed in to the function.

Comment: @arxanas: `dataType - The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html).` (optional last argument of `$.get`)

Comment: Try replacing `$(this).attr("myPlantCode")` with `this.myPlantCode`.

Comment: would help if you told us what 'result' is meant to look like

Comment: @arxanas - thanks. Tried that (as well as ("v.myPlantCode") it threw 'undefined' (and I've placed breakpoints to allow me to view the object as it's passed through, so I know there's real data there...)

Comment: @nav - thanks. The 'result' is a json array of simple text strings. When i print each value "v" to the console, it shows me a list of "Objects", and I can expand each (using Safari's developers console) to see the various attributes, but when i try to call an attribute by that name, it keeps throwing "undefined".

Comment: @BenBernards can you inspect the XHR request response and paste us the body of that please?

Comment: @nav - here's what I have:


Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 09 Apr 2012 15:58:22 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=96
Server:Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.8 with Suhosin-Patch
Transfer-Encoding:Identity
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.8

Comment: @BenBernards those are the headers..i need to know the response body - id suggest using chrome dev tools if you dont know how to get at it in safari

Comment: @nav - no worries mate, I got it figured out. Turns out the object was wrapped in another object. (I was able to get it with console.log(v.Site.myPlantCode));. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah...I knew it was something stupidly silly. 
console.log (v.Site.myPlantCode) worked, because the Parsed result gave an array of objects wrapped in objects. Now to see if I can get the data without parsing the JSON unnecessarily.